# Set persistent routing table on Debian

Tags: debian, networking, route

I have modified my routing table by deleting one rule, and adding two new rules for my second interface eth1:

```
route del -net 10.1.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
route add -host 10.1.2.51 eth1
route add -host 10.1.2.52 eth1
```

I want the rules to survive reboot. I could write a simple rc script to remove 1 rule and insert 2 new, but I was wondering whether there is a way to configure ifconfig, not to add a route rule for the interface (eth1) when it is started, or even better, to specify which rules should be added.

What would be a clean way to do it? Does `ifconfig` allow me to specify custom rules for routing?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add the calls to the `post-up` hook when the interface comes up. The
interface configuration sits in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Here an example:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
  post-up route del -net 10.1.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
  post-up route add -host 10.1.2.51 eth1
  post-up route add -host 10.1.2.52 eth1
  pre-down route add -net 10.1.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
  pre-down route add -host 10.1.2.51 eth1
  pre-down route add -host 10.1.2.52 eth1
```

From the [man page - interfaces](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=interfaces&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+7.0+wheezy&format=html&locale=en):

> **post-up** `command`
>                 Run command after bringing the interface up.   If  this  command
>                 fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as
>                 configured (even though it has really been  configured),  prints
>                 an  error  message,  and exits with status 0.
>
> **pre-down** `command`
>                 Run command before taking the interface down.  If  this  command
>                 fails  then  ifdown  aborts, marks the interface as deconfigured
>                 (even though it has not really  been  deconfigured),  and  exits
>                 with status 0.

Furthermore, on Linux the “net-tools” `route` is deprecated and should be replaced
by the tools from the [iproute2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) package.

Further reading:

- [Linux Set Up Routing with ip Command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-configuring-default-route-with-ipcommand/)
- [IPROUTE2 Utility Suite Howto](http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html#ss9.5.1)

Comment: could I, instead of removing the first rule, prevent it from being created in the first place? How does a route rule get created, anyway? From the network settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`? And how do I know, that when post-up runs, the rule-to-be-removed already exists? The man page does not say at what point in time it's created.

Comment: Since I neither know your network nor your host configuration, I can't tell how this route made it's way into the routing table. Does it come with a DHCP lease? If not, check your services in `/etc/init.d` and investigate which ones possibly could tinker with the routing table. Also have a look into `/etc/network` including subdirectories.

Comment: `post-up` and `pre-down` are aliases for `up` and `down`, respectively.  And adding a `|| :` at the end of a line allows the command to fail and not disturb ifup/ifdown.  I usually add this to `route del`, in case the route does not exist yet and hence cannot be removed.